# Does classical physics allow a flow of electrons in vacuum to form a current?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, photoelectric-effect, classical-field-theory

My physics teacher today proposed this question as a homework. My view is that it does allow the current to flow classically.

Comment: Don't just tell us what you think the answer is.  Tell us why you think that.  It's not very useful to anyone if we simply give an answer.  The reasoning behind the answer is more important than the answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are several types of currents.  Most often in circuits one encounters so-called conduction currents (which occur through a conducting material) but there are also more generally conduction currents:

> A current is the transfer of electric charges by the movement of a
>   charged body. From the viewpoint of electron theory, any transfer of
>   charges is, in the final analysis, due to the convection (or movement)
>   of charged microparticles.

*Source: the Great Soviet Encyclopedia, 3rd edition.*

Examples of conduction currents which are not conduction currents include the transfer of charge between the interior and exterior surface of a star, or the motion of charged clouds.
Thus, the flow of charge through a vacuum tube does constitute a current.  Indeed, in accelerator physics, one often refers to the intensity of the beam as a current.

The "orbiting motion" of a single electron around a hydrogen nucleus, or the motion of quarks inside a proton, are also examples of currents.  In fact, one of the early hints that the proton contained constituents was its magnetic moment, and magnetic moments are associated with currents.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is NO, current cannot flow in vacuum as vacuum contains no atoms of any element and hence no electrons.
I ll explain this in a bit more detail. 
First off,we all know that electric current is constituted by a flow of electrons across a material due to a potential difference between the ends of a material.In the atoms of any material,the electrons in the orbit close to it are bound to the atoms under the strong attraction of the nuclear positive charge. But in electrons in the outer orbits far from the nucleus experience a much weaker attractive force. Hence outer electrons can be removed easily from the atoms ( by rubbing or heating the substance) . In fact,a few outer electrons leave their atoms and move freely within the substance ( in the vacant spaces between the atoms) . These electrons are called "free electrons" or "conduction" electrons,and it is these free electrons that flow under the influence of an applied potential difference (voltage) and constitiute electric current.
Since vacuum has no atoms,and thus no electrons (free or otherwise) current can flow in vacuum as per the classical electron theory of current.

Comment: How do you account for the operation of vacuum tubes?

Comment: In the vacuum tubes there is a emitter plate maintained at a negative potential and a collector plate at a positive potential. So ,it's from the emitter plate that the electrons come from,thus solving the issue of electrons. This slipped my mind.thanks for reminding @thephoton

Comment: And yet there can be a current between the plates, through a space that is (other than the electrons themselves) a vacuum.